# On setting New Magento 2.4.2 Version Front-end is messy

Tags: magento2, error, frontend, magento2.4.2

On Setting Magento 2 Store with version 2.4.2 my front-end is messy like [image].

i have removed my var cache folders and pub->static folders and run

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and then clear cache and given permission but the issue is still there i have checked the .htaccess file it will be there in pub->static

**When i check the console it will load the path http://mag24.local/static/version1620651126/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js
without pub before the static so it will become messy i think.**

Any idea whats the issue and how to solve this ?

Comment: You Should not remove the pub > static folder fully there will .htaccess file it should not be deleted. Please push .htaccess file if you have any backup. Then run the below commands.php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands to thoroughly upgrade compile and deploy your code.

Upgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Compile

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Cache Clear

```
php bin/magento cache:clean or cache:flush
```

Grant Permission

```
chmod 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/*
```

You can run a combined command for everything.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade && 
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && 
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && 
sudo chown 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/* && 
sudo php bin/magento c:f && 
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ../mag24/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Sign Static Files under Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Static File Settings.

Also run this

```
rm -rf var/di/* ;
rm -rf var/generation/* ;
rm -rf var/cache/* ;
rm -rf var/log/* ;
rm -rf var/page_cache/* ;
rm -rf var/session/* ;
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* ;
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*;
rm -rf pub/static/adminthml/*;

bin/magento setup:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:di:compile;
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
bin/magento indexer:reindex;
bin/magento cache:clean;
bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

before you run the deploy

Answer (score 0):

Your domain has to point to the `/pub/` directory.

In earlier versions, you could choose to point your domain either to `/` or `/pub/`.
In 2.4, I experienced issues with pointing the domain to `/`.